# Date format in underscore template(javascript)

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have gone through the questions asked about date format in stackoverflow and i have found numerous ones marked duplicate. I am posting this after trying out various methods that they have accepted as answer but i cannot somehow get it to work.

First of all i am using backbone.

What i have is a date format in (Y-m-d) which comes from database. Through json parsing i get it into the underscore template. I need it to be in (m-d-Y) format.

Value from database

```
data.pp.dob
```

What i tried (to convert it into m-d-Y format)

```
var date = new Date(data.pp.dob);
dateNew = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
```

I am using jquery datepicker plugin to get the calender. So everything is going wierd when i try to format date. Sometimes it will give NAN when i try to trigger calender. Sometimes it will give the year like in 4400 and all..

```
    $('.date-picker').datepicker();
```

HTML code

```
   <%
   var date = new Date(data.pp.dob);
   dateNew = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
   %>
   <%=dateNew%>
   <input value="<%=dateNew%>"  class="span5 date-picker dob" name="dob" id="id-date-picker-1" type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming date you receive from backend is correct, most probable issue lies here:

```
<input value="<%=dateNew%>"  class="span5 date-picker dob" name="dob" id="id-date-picker-1" type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

Datepicker widget has some strange convention:

- y - year (two digit)
- yy - year (four digit)

So, format for input should be: *yy-mm-dd* documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: quite correct. I changed the date format in the widget to mm-dd-yyyy and it worked perfect. Thanks drax.. :)

Comment: sharing the correct code : 

<%
var date = new Date(data.pp.dob);
dateNew = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
%>
<input value="<%=dateNew%>"  class="span5 date-picker dob" name="dob" id="id-date-picker-1" type="text" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" />